# My app need to remember the status of like button

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

As you can see I'm uploaded my code related to like button where if we tap on like button it will make increments and decrement count but after closing and re-opening my app it will again ask to like a post.
where my problem is that the like button status is not remaining true after re-opening the app.

where I'm storing likes count and liked by user id also into Firestore but I don't know where I'm wrong

Can any one help me with this problem

```
 bool isLiked = false;
 onTap: () async {
                        FirebaseUser user =
                            await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
                        List<String> userId = [user.uid];
                        if (!isLiked) {
                          setState(() {
                            isLiked = true;
                          });
                          await Firestore.instance
                              .collection('posts')
                              .document(postidentifer.postList[index].id)
                              .updateData(
                            {
                              "likes": FieldValue.increment(1),
                              "likedbyuser": FieldValue.arrayUnion(userId),
                            },
                          );
                        } else {
                          setState(() {
                            isLiked = false;
                          });
                          await Firestore.instance
                              .collection('posts')
                              .document(postidentifier.postList[index].id)
                              .updateData(
                            {
                              "likes": FieldValue.increment(-1),
                              "likedbyuser": FieldValue.arrayRemove(userId),
                            },
                          );
                        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use something to save your data, it can be online like firestore or local like shared preferences or sqlite

For this case (small data) try it :
https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences

Comment: Thanks for your response Can you explain it in detail how to do it? because I'm a beginner for flutter

Comment: In your case ,just see this, he make an app like you want
 https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences/example

Comment: sir can you help me with the below issue

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer now I'm done with my like button status  but I'm facing another problem that like button status is changing for all the users who are all authenticated   how can i make it for a particular user.

and also

I'm facing the issue while pressing on like button all the post which having like button turning to favorite animation .

Is there any solution to overcome from that

Here is my updated code

```
 Container(
                                  child: IconButton(
                                    icon: Icon(
                                      liked
                                          ? Icons.favorite_border
                                          : Icons.favorite,
                                      color:
                                          liked ? Colors.grey : Colors.red,
                                    ),
                                    onPressed: () async {
                                      setState(() => liked = !liked);
                                      var preferences =
                                          await SharedPreferences
                                              .getInstance();
                                      preferences.setBool(likedKey, liked);
                                      FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth
                                          .instance
                                          .currentUser();
                                      List<String> userId = [user.uid];
                                      if (!liked) {
                                        setState(() {
                                          isLiked = false;
                                        });
                                        await Firestore.instance
                                            .collection('posts')
                                            .document(postidentifier
                                                .postList[index].id)
                                            .updateData(
                                          {
                                            "likes":
                                                FieldValue.increment(1),
                                            "likedbyuser":
                                                FieldValue.arrayUnion(
                                                    userId),
                                          },
                                        );
                                      } else {
                                        setState(() {
                                          isLiked = true;
                                        });
                                        await Firestore.instance
                                            .collection('posts')
                                            .document(postidentifier
                                                .postList[index].id)
                                            .updateData(
                                          {
                                            "likes":
                                                FieldValue.increment(-1),
                                            "likedbyuser":
                                                FieldValue.arrayRemove(
                                                    userId),
                                          },
                                        );
                                      }
                                    },
                                  ),
                                ),
```